# Почему в selenium send_keys пропускает символы при вводе строки в input?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

В Selenium ввожу строку в `input` с помощью `send_keys`:

```
input_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('fam')
input_form.send_keys('Иванов')
time.sleep(3)
input_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('nam')
input_form.send_keys('Иван')
time.sleep(3)
input_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('otch')
input_form.send_keys('Иванович')
time.sleep(3)
```

Но вводятся только некоторые символы, а часть пропущена. Кто может сказать, почему некорректно форма заполняется?

[image: 1]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса // и ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: Попробуйте вводить символы по одному, как вам предложили в ответе или заполните поля с помощью JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Такая проблема возникает, в частности, в случае, если на `input`-е есть javascript обработчик, который перед тем как значение попадет собственно в `input` делает что-то дополнительное. Например, проверяет формат введенных данных или допустимость символов.

Selenium посылает символы без задержки и некоторые пропускаются.

Избежать этой проблемы можно посылая символы по одному и ожидая, что предыдущий уже точно обработан. Для этого можно использовать функцию типа такой:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def send_keys_with_delays(element, value):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    for i in range(len(value)):
        element.send_keys(value[i])
        wait.until(lambda _: element.get_property('value')[:i] == value[:i])
```

Теперь вместо:

```
input_form.send_keys('Иванов')
```

используем:

```
send_keys_with_delays(input_form, 'Иванов')
```